# Maximum size of an SQL prepared statement from java to DB2

Tags: java, mysql, db2

I am using an 'in' statement as part of my query to DB2 an I am dynamically adding the ID numbers to my query via a preparedStatement. Code shown below. I am trying to determine the maximum size query the system will allow me to send it.

```
if (Ids.size() > 1){
                int temp = Ids.size();
                while (temp >1){
                    query.insert(Query.indexOf("?") + 1, ", ?");
                    temp-=1;

                }
                    stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());

                for (int i=1 ; i<=Ids.size(); i++){
                    stmt.setInt( i, Ids.get(i-1).intValue());
                }
```

I found documentation from IBM regarding DB2 here : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQP76_8.9.0/com.ibm.odm.distrib.config.wlp/shared_config_topics/tsk_res_setup_db.html

This states that the maximum size is

> max_allowed_packet=1073741824

How would I use this information to determine how many entries I can search for at one time considering my query has a static length of 516 characters? Is the answer simply taking the default allowable size of 1GB and subtract my static size to give me the amount I have left for entries or am i missing some other limitations to the size?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzlimtabs.htm use this link document

Comment: that link says **Maximum length of an SQL statement (in bytes) 2 097 152** So the rest of my information is correct i just need to use this much smaller  number  (2mb?) but i apply the same method?

Comment: If a 2Gb limit is an issue then consider using temporary tables instead.

Comment: 2GB limit wouldn't be an issue, but i am trying to make sure that i have the correct information, or if i am wrong one the size?

Comment: Test  it and verify with the DB2-platforms and versions that you target, along with the jdbc driver versions and encodings you target.  Some versions of DB2 had issues with very long IN lists but I think such issues are fixed in currently supported versions.

Comment: tests are currently ongoing, while a precise answer would be optimal, i think i am going to  use temp tables just for longevity/scalability anyway.I just feel like it is using a Ferrari instead of a lawn tractor just because we are not absolutely sure the lawn tractor will make it.